# Pycharm says no boto3 module even though I installed

Tags: python, module, pycharm, boto3

Hii am using pycharm IDE, I wanted to use boto3 module and installed successfully. But my python program keep saying module boto3 not found ..I verified interpreter it all correct ...can some one suggest

Comment: Do you run it in PyCharm or in the terminal?

Comment: pycharm only...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it through pycharm or simply install it through your terimnal?

Comment: Via pycharm only